# How to improve query performance on larger table? Since partition is not a feature for it, what's the. best. way to use the partitioned. table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, partitioning

before now, i though the. partition could improve the larger table query performance, but after testing, it seems that the partition doesn't improve the. performance significantly.
after searching, i found the partition is better used to backup, index management. There is a way to improve the performance, keep the newest data in a special file group which is localed in a quick driver,.such as SSD. But, could someone provide a demo with.code to.explain this process? how to.keep.the.newest data in a special filegeoup and how to move the old data into backup driver?
are There anyother ways to performance the query on a 10m table in less 1 second?

Comment: Partition is the way to go for large tables,may be you are not getting partition elimination

Comment: Partitioning isn't a performance feature and 10M isn't that big a table. What is the *query plan*? DO you have the appropriate indexes? 10M isn't such a big table that it requires partitioning. Besides, if you use a query that has to scan multiple partitions you'll end up with a slower query

Comment: What is the query that you want to speed up? What does it do? Running aggregates for 1M rows is always going to be slower than retrieving 1 row by ID

Comment: Performance tuning is a big & complex subject.  **SO** big in fact that [whole books are dedicated to this stuff](https://www.amazon.co.uk/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=sql+server+performance+tuning).  To get you started; the nice people over at @BrentOzar have produced [a guide](https://www.brentozar.com/sql/sql-server-performance-tuning/).

Comment: ok, thank you all for your comments.      Based on your suggestions,i know the 10m is nor bif enough to use partition. But, from the management angles, if the table grows big.enoug, how do.i make sure the newest records comes into a special file group? How do i move the old data to.the backup file group? I.think, .keeping newest record in quick drive is a good.idea to improve the performance, am i right?